# Datagrid or Table in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, datagrid

I am looking out for a datagrid or a table (something like DisplayTag in JSP, JTable or similar) in JavaFx.

I did find couple of implementations but none of them have clear documentation. Is there some alternative or a good api (with good documentation) that I could use?

I have already looked into crudfx, jfxtras.

Comment: You should specify which options you already know about, otherwise we'll probably just end up naming them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaFX 1.3, look at com.javafx.preview.layout.Grid. In JavaFX 2.0 there will be a TableView Control as well as a Grid Layout Container ( no longer in preview state).

Answer (score 1):

Try [DataFX](http://www.javafxdata.org/), they have a pretty good implementation for TableViews.